# tool to "flatten" LaTeX sources to a single directory, for ex. before journal submission

Tags: journal-publishing

When I write a paper, I typically use a separate file with definitions and put figures into a separate directory. Moreover, I might have sources for the figures and other other extra files in the paper's directory.
This works fine up to the point where I want to send the paper to a journal. Then I want to send only the files actually required for compilation. Moreover, many journals don't accept directories, so the directory structure has to be "flattened".

*Is there a tool that can do this*? The tool should work on Windows with MiKTeX and be able to:

1. given the main source, file copy it to a given directory (let's call it TGDIR)
2. copy all included source files to TGDIR, rewriting the include command if they were in another dir.
3. copy all used figures to TGDIR, again rewriting the include command if needed
4. make a .bib file including only the cited references and copy it to TGDIR

   - it would be nice if the tool could find .bib files in the main TeX tree
5. update the source so it uses the new .bib file

If there is no tool that can do all of the above, I would also be grateful for tips about things that can do only some of the steps - then it should be command-line tools, so I can use them in a script.

So far, I have found several tools for 4., but only [bibfish](https://github.com/jwcarr/bibfish) worked for me on Windows without a need to compile things (I want something I can recommend to others as well). I know that Jabref can do it as well, but I got mixed results when using it from command line.

I have also found [texdirflatten](https://ctan.org/pkg/texdirflatten) which claims to do 1.-3., but it did not handle figures - and it has not been updated in 6 years...

Comment: see latexpand utility that's distributed with# texlive

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks. `latexpand` solves 1. and 2. (in a way), but not the rest. It is distributed with MiKTeX as well.

Comment: for 4 and 5 why bother? I'd just remove`\bibliography` and simply `\input` the generated .bbl which will be in your local directory anyway.

Comment: Some journals want the .bib file, since they do their own processing etc

Comment: sure but don't such journals accept a zip of the original layout and not need it flattened at all?

Comment: There is a tool in texlive I think that does make a subset bib from a document, I forget the name.

Comment: There are two: bibexport is a bash-script (and hence won't work on Windows) and bibtool is not available in MiKTeX and is otherwise distributed only as source (C)

Comment: I use bash on windows all the time:-)

Comment: https://davidstutz.de/python-scripts-to-prepare-arxiv-submissions/ claims to do some of 1-3.